# PS4 parental controls by user?

Tags: ps4

I just got a PS4. I've created local users for my kids, as "sub accounts" without a linked PSN IDs. I read somewhere that if you go into a sub account and configure Parental Controls, the settings will only affect that account, but this does not seem to be the case - if I switch back to my main login, M-rated games still show the padlock icon and refuse to start.

I can go into the Settings menu and remove the restriction to play, but then I have to remember to turn it back on when I'm done. Is there really no way to play higher-rated games without ​toggling the settings every time?

Comment: Is it important that they be able to play online?

Comment: No. The local accounts are primarily so they can keep track of their own saved games.